# Deskew Image using fitted ellipse opencv

Tags: opencv, image-rotation, ellipse, skew

I am attempting to deskew an image (containing a 'digit') using the returned angle from opencv's fitellipse against the binary thresholded image.

I have attempted (not shown here) to use the various workarounds for the returned image, but the digit in the image is never vertically aligned as shown in the results.

[image]
[image]

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

int affineFlags = WARP_INVERSE_MAP|INTER_LINEAR;
Mat input = Imgcodecs.imread("4.png");
Mat grayImage = new Mat(input.size(), CV_8UC1 );

// convert the frame in gray scale
Imgproc.cvtColor(input, grayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

Core.bitwise_not(grayImage, grayImage);
Mat threshold = new Mat(grayImage.rows(), grayImage.cols(),grayImage.type());
Imgproc.threshold(grayImage, threshold, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU);

Imgcodecs.imwrite("threshold.png", threshold);
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

Imgproc.findContours(threshold, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

double angle=0;

for(MatOfPoint mp : contours)
{
    //RotatedRect rr = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(mp.toArray()));

    if(mp.total() > 35) // Cheat to find the biggest contour.
    {
        RotatedRect elipse = Imgproc.fitEllipse(new MatOfPoint2f(mp.toArray()));
        Imgproc.ellipse(input, elipse, new Scalar(0,255,0));
        angle = elipse.angle;               
    }

}

Imgcodecs.imwrite("elipse.png", input);

Point center = new Point(threshold.cols() /2 ,threshold.rows()/2);

Mat rotMat = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center,angle , 1.0 );
Mat imgOut = Mat.zeros(input.rows(), input.cols(), input.type());
Imgproc.warpAffine(threshold, imgOut, rotMat, imgOut.size(), affineFlags);
Imgcodecs.imwrite("Rotated.png", imgOut);
```

[image: Original]
[image: Elipse]

Comment: Do you have some sample images to give context as to what the input is and what the expected output is?

Comment: I have added the images to the post. they seem to have gone out of order, but hopefully you can see the greyscale "4" original, the fitted ellipse, the thresholded version, and the resulting rotated thresholded version, which is obviously not vertically aligned!